# How to get the latest created table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database and every 6 months, a new table is created with the latest entries. What SQL command can get you the latest created table in a database?

Many thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can select the last `create_time` from `information_schema.TABLES`.

For example:

```
select table_name, create_time 
from information_schema.TABLES
where table_schema = 'andomar'
order by CREATE_TIME desc
limit 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can display from a particular database

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE table_schema = 'database_name'
ORDER BY `TABLES`.`CREATE_TIME` DESC
```

Comment: This is basically Andomar's answer, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL stores this info in the `information_schema` database, so you'll be able to get the info from there i you have access to it.