# Display newest tables in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I can't seem to find a way to identify the latest tables created within a database. Is this possible using PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808042/how-to-get-the-latest-created-table-in-mysql . you can execute the query from answer within phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Hopefully the question gets marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run this query:

```
select table_name, create_time 
from information_schema.TABLES
where table_schema = 'andomar'
order by CREATE_TIME desc
limit 1
```